# How do you set default zoom for an embedded document(Visio) in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, frontend, sharepoint-online, visio, sharepoint-designer

I have tried to add the &z=15 and %zoom=15 to try to edit the default zoom in the embed code but it seems to not change anything. Also, I have changed up the width and height of the embed code but that didn't change the zoom just the overall dimensions. I am trying to embed a flowchart into my company's intranet SharePoint but the zoom is always set to 19% or 24% by default which makes it impossible to see anything in the diagram by default. I want it to start zoomed in at like 100% so the website/diagram is easier to use.
I have also tried to print it in a pdf, converting it to pdf, and converting it to other formats for the file viewer to give different views but it came to no avail. The closest thing was when I changed it to pdf and it gave me a better view, but I lost the interactive embed that a normal Visio embed would give.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puzzled with a similar problem, I've built a special Web Part for that (it provides additional options for embedding that are not part of the stock web part, such as zoom).

The source code:
https://github.com/nbelyh/VisioOnlineSpfxWebPart

Here web part in MS Store: https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/wa200002491

Comment: Okay, thank you, I will check that out! I sent a request in the MS store if you could approve that.

Comment: What kind of request? Anyone should be able to install actually... in case you can install any third-party application at all in your organization you should be able to install this one as well. I mean, from my side, there is nothing to approve, it is just like a AppStore for android/iphone, you don't author to approve your install :)

Comment: it says there's request setting. might be my organizational request though. Thought it was seeking permission from you, but it might be my company that has to approve actually.  Here's what it looks like. https://imgur.com/a/52MSJxx

Comment: Quick update, the download works now, I got the app up and running and so far it works great for Visio. I was wondering if there is a way to add the same functionality to pdf or excel documents?

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding &wdZoom={your desired zoom level} src parameter of iframe, you can set default zoom level.